# sendJavascript function not defined error in Cordova Plugin salesforce

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a salesforce plugin in which i want to push data back to JS from my java code (which is basically a background process)
But its always giving me error for line this.sendJavascript(function name)

following is plugin code -

```
package com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
    private static final String TAG = "CordovaPlugin";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Log.i(TAG,"inside execute method--->>>" + action + args + callbackContext);
        if (action.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("echo")) {
            Log.i(TAG,"args.getString(0)--->>>" + args.getString(0));
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            // Initialise the service variables and start it it up
            Context thiscontext = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Intent callBackgroundService = new Intent(thiscontext, CallBackgroundService.class);
            callBackgroundService.putExtra("loadinterval", 800); // Set LED flash interval
            thiscontext.startService(callBackgroundService);
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);

            sendValue("Kaushik", "Ray");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

    public void sendValue(String value1, String value2) {
         JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("value1", "Kaushik");
            data.put("value2", "Ray");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("CommTest", e.getMessage());
        }
         String js = String.format(
                "window.plugins.commtest.updateValues('%s');",
                data.toString());
    error line ------->>>  this.sendJavascript(js);

    }
}
```

I have marked the error line which is at the end. Please help me resolve this

Thanks in Advance,
Kaushik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendJavascript()` is a function in both DroidGap.java and CordovaWebView.java, but the value of `this` in your current file is your instance of Echo.  The line `this.sendJavascript()` fails because is expecting the function called to be a member of Echo or a public/protected member of one of the classes it inherited from, in this case CordovaPlugin.

There is a public variable in CordovaPlugin.java, named `webView` which is the CordovaWebView for your project.  If you change your offending line from `this.sendJavascript(js)` to `webView.sendJavascript(js)`, it should fix your error.

Comment: Actually I just resolved the issue..!! thanks for helping..!!I had one other doubt I am calling a background service class as mentioined in  code called CallBackgroundService.java, but I am not able to pass values back to JS from my Service in android...any pointer plz...??

Comment: Happy to hear that you've got things figured out.  As for your other issue, without seeing some code I'm not really sure, but it sounds like that might be something worth posting another question about!