# cordova send message to javascript

Tags: cordova

Im using Cordova-Android (PhoneGap). I'm extending the `CordovaWebViewClient` class, overriding the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. I need to send some javascript to the view. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
             sendJavascript("javascript:alert('OK')");
             return false;
         } else {
             sendJavascript("javascript:alert('NO')");
             return true;
         }
     }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. I've never made an Android plugin, but this post may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404492/sendjavascript-function-not-defined-error-in-cordova-plugin-salesforce

Comment: @gaepi hi, since it's only one line of code originating in the Java layer itself, I was hoping that a plugin wasn't necessary. Ill take a look anyways. Thanks.